Add a new JSON object to an existing list array firebase firestore
My app has a feature where users can add their reviews. For example, it's like leaving a comment on Facebook. posting a user review should be stored in the reviews list. I think it can't be done this way .doc(DocId).update(review.toJson()).
This is a screenshot of the data structure of my Firebase Firestore.

I tried to solve this firestore.FieldValue if I do that, an error message will come like this: I/flutter (21250): type '_Map<String, String?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
this is my Firestore query.
Future<void> addReview (placeId,Review review) async{

    try{

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('attractions')
      .where('placeId',isEqualTo: placeId).get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
        for (var ele in querySnapshot.docs) {

            FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('attractions')
            .doc(ele.id)
            .update({
              'reviews': FieldValue.arrayUnion(review.toJson())});
          
        }

      });

    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
    
  }



}

this is my review.dart model class :
class Review {

  final String reviewId;
  final String? name;
  final String publishAt;
  final String? reviewerPhotoUrl;
  final String text;

  Review({
    required this.reviewId,
    required this.name,
    required this.publishAt,
    required this.reviewerPhotoUrl,
    required this.text,
  });

  toJson ()=>{
    "reviewId":reviewId,
    "name":name,
    "publishAt":publishAt,
    "reviewerPhotoUrl":reviewerPhotoUrl,
    "text":text
  };

  

}


I think there is a way around this or there is an alternative to doing this.

Try Using :
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('attractions')
            .doc(ele.id)
            .update({
              'reviews': [review.toJson()]});

I think your review type on firestore is List still it is not working provide proper typing

In this method, the existing data will be lost and new data will be added, so this method is not successful.

When you iterate through querySnapshot.docs the ele object is of type QueryDocumentSnapshot. So there is no need to create a reference you can simply call reference. Besides that, the review is an object of type Review, so as far as I know there is no need to map the object to JSON, you can directly pass the object. So in code, it will be as simple as:
//    
ele.reference.update({
    'reviews': FieldValue.arrayUnion(review)
}); //                                

If you want to add the object as a Map, then you should define it as:
Map<String, dynamic> review = {
  'reviewId': reviewId,
  'name': name,
  'publishAt': publishAt,
  'reviewerPhotoUrl': reviewerPhotoUrl,
  'text': text
};


Hey Chamalka. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

I tried this, but still have same problem

What happens if you try to add the object to the array without calling .toJson()?

same thing as before  I/flutter (21250): type '_Map<String, String?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

The firebase query did not do what I wanted. That's why I made some small changes in my code. I assigned the current reviews to a list variable. After that, the newly created review was added to the reviews list. Its working fine now
 void addReview (){

    List currentReviews = place.reviews;

    
    if(reviewTextController.text.isNotEmpty){
      var uuid = const Uuid();
      
      final newReview = {
        "reviewId": uuid.v1(),
        "name": userName,
        "publishAt": DateTime.now().toString(), 
        "reviewerPhotoUrl": proPic, 
        "text": reviewTextController.text
      };

      currentReviews.add(newReview);
      
      BlocProvider.of<placeListBloc>(context).add(addReviewEvent(currentReviews, searchType, placeId));

    }

  }

